# WordPress multi-site domain mapping causing white screen

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

We have a WordPress multi-site, the primary domain is star-emea.com. We have 6 sub-sites to this which are: star-russia.com, star-meast.com, futureprnt.com, mpop.com, kasseninnovationen.com and starvip.club.

They all work fine except for the starvip.club one. This used to work fine and then all of a sudden it just shows a white screen now. Also when we add a new site now and map a domain to it, it just shows the whitescreen.

We've tried lots of things to try and get it working, including:

- When we unmap the domain the subfolder address works fine star-emea.com/starvip
- Change the theme to one of the others sub site themes that works
- Network deactivate all plugins
- Point a different domain and map this
- Change from the default WordPress domain mapping to the [Mercator](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator) domain mapping
- Create a new site in the multi-site and map a domain to it
- Changing the htaccess to [WordPress recommended one](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Multisite)
- Enabled WP_DEBUG and fix any errors. After visiting starvip.club it does not seem to trigger an error in the server error log right away

All of these scenarios end up with the white screen again, yet the other 5 sub-sites and the main site work fine still.

We feel this may have something to do with it... the only error in the server error logs is:

```
star-emea.com [Wed Jun 27 11:09:32 2018] [error] [client 193.201.224.210:37314] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

My htaccess is:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 7

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My wp-config is (sensored some info):

```
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', false);

define ('WPLANG', 'en_GB');

define('SUNRISE', true);

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXX');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXX');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'XXXX');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'XXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'XXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'XXXX');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'XXXX');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'XXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'XXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'XXXX');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'XXXX');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

/**
 *  Change this to true to run multiple blogs on this installation.
 *  Then login as admin and go to Tools -> Network
 */

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'star-emea.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'SUNRISE', 'true' );


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

/* Destination directory for file streaming */
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');
```